# Display large image after hover a link

Tags: html, css, hover

I have shop on Prestashop 1.6. I created a third view in product list. With one thing, I can't handle by myself. When You move cursor over image (in third view), it display next to it with large size and this is ok. How can I move this image a little bit more to right. If I use margin-left or padding-left, image is flashes. I hope You know what I mean.

```
  <div class="left image">
   <a href="#">
<img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="/1-home_default/faded-short-sleeve-tshirts.jpg" width="250" height="250"></a></div>

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.image{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}

.image a:hover img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Thanks for help.
Kind regards

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Check [How-To-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the within linked article on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I my opinion the faster way is share the link. I add code.

Comment: what is "third view"?

Comment: Widok: Flat list. Next to Grid, List view. Do You see ?

Comment: @user3531797 It is not about whats faster its about how useful the question is going forward. for other users besides yourself. When your website changes or the link goes dead, the question becomes redundant and is of no use to any future user with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an invisible border on the image that loads.

```
border-left: 10px transparent;
```

This should give you the space you need, and stop the flashing that occurs when using margin. However the image will still show when hovering this border. It really depends what outcome you desire.

Comment: Like this ?      

.image a:hover img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-left: 50px transparent;
}

Comment: Absolutely, so [this is essentially](https://s24.postimg.org/52dlqoj91/image.png) what happens. However the mouse would need to leave the border as well, before the image closes.